# I want to install UBUNTU 12.10 , on a partition that I have created

Tags: 12.10, partitioning

I wanted to install 12.10, but also wanted to keep Windows 8, so I created another partition E:
with 29GB space, and now I want to install Ubuntu on that partition is that possible in any way?

Comment: possible duplicated: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/62483)

Comment: as far as i know, it depends on a few things.  first off, is this new partition (E:) at the end of the disk, or the beginning?  windows will generally see any drive beginning with a EXE-based partition as completely corrupt, and refuse to touch the drive.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that a couple of days ago. I didn't trust the automatic option so I chose to do it manually during installation, picked the unallocated partition and set it to ext4, made the mountpoint /, and reduced the size by 8GB. Then I made another partition (in the empty 8GB), set it to swap. Make sure you have a backup! It is very possible to screw it up by making a mistake. It put in a good boot loader and I could pick Win7 or Ubuntu during boot. So the answer is "yes". Is there something more specific you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this link (if you have a new pc with window 8 logo) :)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI